# How to exclude non-western characters from a text file?

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I would like to exclude non-western characters and words from a text file. I do not know how to insert the text file here, but I suppose you can do without it. All your suggestions will be much appreciated.

Update: I have used:

```
Alphabet["Russian"]
Select[dict21, Not@StringContainsQ[#, Alternatives @@ dict24Russion] &]
```

The problem is that there are several alphabets in the text (even unknown). There must be some solution of kind "include only `Alphabet[]`". What do you think?

Comment: You simply wish to delete all characters which are not from `Alphabet[]`?

Comment: Exactly. Russian was just an example.

Comment: You can post your text file at https://pastebin.com/ and provide a link in your question.

Comment: @JSP `LanguageIdentify` may be useful. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4SK7.png

Comment: What does "Western" even mean?  I find it a very weird description.

Comment: By "Western", you mean just the Latin letters, right? No diacritics or anything?

Comment: Quite so, only Latin letters.

Answer (score 6):

How to delete all characters except from a list.

First, here is a string containing all the characters currently supported by `String` in the Wolfram Language:

```
allSupportedCharacters = FromCharacterCode@Range[0, 65535];
```

And here is a list of characters you wish to keep in the string:

```
list = Alphabet[];
```

Processing the string:

```
StringReplace[allSupportedCharacters, Except[list] -> ""]
```

> ```
> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
> ```

or alternatively

```
StringDelete[allSupportedCharacters, Except[list]]
```

> ```
> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
> ```

---

#### EDIT

Per request from a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155897/how-to-exclude-non-western-characters-from-a-text-file#comment416137_155900):

```
StringReplace[Import["https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategori:Sjötermer"], 
 Except[list] -> ""]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. However, Mathematica says "The argument Except[list] is not a valid string pattern"

Comment: @JSP Which *Mathematica* version do you use?

Comment: version 10.3.0.0

Comment: @JSP I have no access to version 10.3.0 but with version 10.4.1 my code works perfectly. Even with version 8.0.4 `StringReplace[allSupportedCharacters, Except[list] -> ""]` works if I set `list = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", 
   "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};`. Are you sure you have reproduced my steps exactly?

Comment: @JSP You haven't defined `list`, otherwise it wouldn't have said `Except[list]` – it would have replaced `list` with whatever you defined it to be in the message.

Comment: I understand. I type list=Alphabet[] as you write and then it gives med "list={a,b,c and so on}". But then, on the next line, I type list (just to check) and it gives me "list". Another thing (from a not so frequent user): The arrow -> that you use, differs from my arrow, taken from the Basic Math Assistant.

Comment: @JSP when you type `list = Alphabet[]` it should be giving you `{"a", "b", ...}`, not `list = {"a", "b", ...}`. If you don't have a lot of unsaved work, try simple evaluating `Quit` and trying again. Somehow `Set` isn't being called for you.

Comment: Did I explain the problem well? I want the long file back, but only with words written with characters from a-z.

Comment: @JSP I think it's explained well enough. Is your `list` still not working? In any case you can also try `StringReplace[Import[file, "Text"], Except[Alternatives@@Alphabet]->""]` if the raw `Except` wasn't working.

Comment: Mathematica has turned very slow. I will restart the Mac and Mathematica. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Could you please try this text (and get rid of non-western characters).        StringReplace[
 Import["https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategori:Sjötermer"], 
 Except[Alternatives @@ Alphabet] -> ""]

Comment: @JSP Please see the "**EDIT**" section in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is especially easy to express the character range `Alphabet[]` that you mention using `RegularExpression`:

```
StringDelete["adeфfgh12cа34", RegularExpression["[^a-z]+"]]
```

> `"adefghc"`

It will also be faster than other options. (Thanks to Alexey for pointing me towards `StringDelete`.)

To do the same for other alphabets I would suggest just looking at what you need beyond the a-z range, then just add that. So in the case of the Swedish alphabet it would be:

```
StringDelete["adeфfgh12cа34", RegularExpression["[^a-zåäö]+"]]
```

Also note that if you need to match capital letters as well then you should use

```
StringDelete["adeфfgh12cа34", RegularExpression["[^A-Za-zÅÄÖåäö]+"]]
```

Furthermore, you might want to add special characters which, while not in the alphabet, are used in Swedish texts:

```
str = "Spörj, forskare, så långt du gitter,
  vad residens som själen har.
  Det bästa svar blir Dumboms svar:
  \"Min vän, hon sitter där hon sitter.\"";
StringDelete[str, RegularExpression["[^A-Za-zÅÄÖåäö\n., –\"]+"]]

(* Out:
"Spörj, forskare, så långt du gitter,
vad residens som själen har.
Det bästa svar blir Dumboms svar
\"Min vän, hon sitter där hon sitter.\""
*)
```

`\n` corresponds to a new line.

Comment: `StringDelete[string, RegularExpression["[^a-z]+"]]` is even more than twice as fast. (+1)

Comment: This works nicely! While we are at it, how to add the Swedish characters, that is characters Alphabet[] and Alphabet["Swedish"] or more generally how to add alphabets? I will now try to learn about RegularExpression too.

Comment: @JSP Unless you need your code to cover arbitrary alphabets then I would just create a specific pattern for the particular alphabet that I'm interested in. I added a note on how to do it for the Swedish alphabet to the answer as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better `StringDelete` than my first method, courtesy of Alexey Popkov:

```
text = Import["https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategori:Sjötermer"];

pattern =
  Except[
   Join[Alphabet["Swedish"], 
    ToUpperCase@Alphabet["Swedish"], {PunctuationCharacter, 
     WhitespaceCharacter}
    ]
   ];

{timing, result} = StringDelete[text, pattern] // RepeatedTiming;
{timing, StringTake[result, 50]}

{0.00033, "Hjälp     Kategori:Sjötermer  

 Från Wikipedia  
 "}
```

Note how fast it is. And note that all it leaves behind are the Swedish diacritics:

```
StringCases[result,
 (Except[WhitespaceCharacter]?(Not@*PrintableASCIIQ))]

{"ä", "ö", "å", "ö", "ä", "å", "ö", "ä", "ä", "å", "ä", "ö", "å", \
"ö", "å", "ä", "ö", "ö", "ö", "ö", "ö", "ä", "ö", "ä", "ö", "å", "ä", \
"ö", "å", "ä", "å", "å", "å", "å", "ä", "ä", "ö", "ö", "ö", "ö", "ö", \
"ö", "å", "å", "ä", "å", "ö", "å", "ö", "ö", "ö", "ä", "ä", "ä", "ö", \
"å", "ä", "ä", "å", "å", "å", "ö", "ä", "ä", "ä", "ä", "å", "ä", "ä", \
"ä", "ä", "ä", "ä", "ä", "ä", "ö", "ö", "ä", "ä", "å", "ö", "ö", "å", \
"ö", "ö", "ä", "ö", "ä", "ä", "å", "ä", "ä", "ä", "å", "‎", "ä", "ä", \
"ä", "ä", "ö", "å", "ä", "ä", "ö", "å"}
```

We can compile it as a regex too, but unsurprisingly we get no noticeable boost:

```
regex =
  RegularExpression@
   StringPattern`PatternConvert[pattern][[1]];

StringDelete[text, regex] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.00032
```

---

Here's a way that works by matching only against `LetterCharacter`:

```
pattern2 =
  Except[
   Join[Function[Join[#, ToUpperCase[#]]]@Alphabet["Swedish"]],
   LetterCharacter
   ];

{timing2, result2} = StringDelete[text, pattern2] // RepeatedTiming;
timing2

0.00042
```

---

Here's a [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html) way:

```
StringJoin@
 StringCases[
  Import["https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategori:Sjötermer"],
  (Alternatives @@ 
     Join[Alphabet["Swedish"], ToUpperCase@Alphabet["Swedish"]]) | 
   PunctuationCharacter | WhitespaceCharacter
  ]
```

Here's an updated regex base method which is faster than the `StringCases` way:

```
regex =
  RegularExpression[
   StringPattern`PatternConvert[(
       RegularExpression["[A-z]+"] |
        Alternatives @@
         Function[Join[#, ToUpperCase[#]]]@

          DeleteCases[Alphabet["Swedish"], 
           Alternatives @@ Alphabet[]]
       ) | PunctuationCharacter | WhitespaceCharacter
     ][[1]]
   ];

StringJoin@
 StringCases[
  text,
  regex
  ]
```

Note that this is much faster than the older method and gives similar results

```
{timing1, result1} =
  StringJoin@
    StringCases[
     text,
     regex
     ] // AbsoluteTiming;
{timing1, StringTake[result1, 100]}

{timing1, result1} =
  StringJoin@
    StringCases[
     text,
     regex
     ] // AbsoluteTiming;
{timing1, StringTake[result1, 100]}

{0.000769, "Hjälp     Kategori:Sjötermer  

 Från Wikipedia  

  Hoppa till:  navigering , sök    

 Termerna har"}
```

Comment: `LetterCharacter?PrintableASCIIQ` is equivalent to much faster `RegularExpression["[A-z]"]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh true. Originally I didn't have the `LetterCharacter` in there, but that caused funky-ness. Except you mean `RegularExpression["[^A-Z]+"]]`, I think. In any add the `RemoveDiacritics` onto C.E.'s answer as a comment.

Comment: It works nicely but I would like to have the whole text in Swedish, the å, ä and ö disappear, "Sjötermer - > Sjtermer"

Comment: @JSP Yeah that's where the `RemoveDiacritics` comes into play. Unless you want to keep those?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov actually it's not quite the same. This preserves punctuation. The regex should be expanded for that.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov see the update. I dug out the old ``StringPattern`PatternConvert`` to build a faster `RegularExpression`. But I could only use it with `StringCases`, of course.

Comment: Good idea! But actually you can use it with `StringDelete` too: ``StringPattern`PatternConvert[Except[Join[Alphabet["Swedish"],ToUpperCase@Alphabet["Swedish"],{PunctuationCharacter,WhitespaceCharacter}]]][[1]]`` works quite well!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov oh of course. Although I think the second element of that `Except` should be `LetterCharacter`, no? Otherwise we're just deleting all the punctuation and whitespace.

Comment: Why `LetterCharacter`? No, the pattern in my comment is for `StringDelete`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov because the `Except` will match as, essentially, a whitespace or punctuation character that isn't a Swedish letter character, if I'm reading it right. Ah wait. No. I had the grouping wrong (a bunch of those funky hidden characters got copied so I just retyped it, but wrong). By the way a ``StringPattern`PatternConvert`` regex is no faster than just passing the pattern, I found.

Comment: Now I see: by the "second element" you meant the second argument of `Except`. Well done!

Comment: Still [my pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155897/how-to-exclude-non-western-characters-from-a-text-file#comment416151_155904) should be faster than your with `LetterCharacter` as the second argument of `Except` (but they aren't equivalent of course).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov interestingly this is a case where the regex compilation does help. I'll change things, make a note of that.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov oh odd it misses some unicode characters. Any idea why?

Comment: Which characters? And which solution?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov huh it's gone now but the `Except` pattern you proposed was leaving some characters when compiled as regex. I probably just missed typed something.

Comment: Awesome. I had to leave but will look at this first thing in the morning. It is past midnight here. Bye for now and thank you very much.

Comment: What a wealth of suggestions, much appreciated! I am digging into them and have learned so much. I have some problem to understand the extra signs (+, - \) that you add at the end of the formulas. I also tried RegularExpression to get rid of the commas but commas somehow belong to the formulas. I know about \n for a LF but how to add a LF at the end of every word so that the whole text becomes a vertical list?

Comment: I know about the function Column[] to make a vertical list-column. The question is how to include LineFeed on RegularExpression. Thank you. Also, when I am ready, should I summarize this conversation?

Comment: @JSP the `"+"` in `"[A-z]+"` is part of standard regex that means 1-or-more. The `"-"` denotes a character range. Since `"A-z"` is a contiguous block in unicode it works. If you want to drop a specific set of characters the easiest thing is probably a second `StringDelete`. On the other hand if you want to ditch all `PunctuationCharacter` just remove `PunctuationCharacter` from the first answer. If you want to split after every word, just use a second `StringSplit`. Generally it's best if you don't summarize the answer in your question.